# Jquery add Click event difficulties

Tags: jquery, function, click, live

I am quite new in Jquery and need help on my following problem:

I am trying to add a Click Function to an existing li elements (sharing same class name) but no success yet.

My html is as follow:

```
<div class="ol_results" style=" display: inherit; width: 100%; top: 276px; left: 175px;">
<ul>
<li class="myorders">
<span id="Orderid" class="orderDetails">1</span>
<span id="orderDate" class="orderDetails">2012/12/20</span>
<span id="DispatchDate" class="orderDetails">Dispatched</span>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and my Jquery is:

```
$('.myorders').live('click', function () { alert("Clicked!") });
```

What have I missed?

Any helps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bind instead of live()

```
$('.myorders').bind('click', function () { 
  alert("Clicked!") 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery 1.9... the `live()` is removed ..so use `on`

```
 $('.ol_results').on('click','.myorders', function () { alert("Clicked!") });
```

or else if your `<li>` is not added dynamically thn you can call directly.

```
$('.myorders').click(function(){alert("Clicked!")});
```

Comment: Note that neither of what you have is a direct replacement for `live()` (see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-live/info)

Comment: The Jquery I am using is 1.2.6

Answer (score 0):

Make use of live() instead of on() for latest versions

```
$('.myorders').on('click', function () { 
     alert("Clicked!") 
});
```